# Google Recaptcha error [invalid-input-response]

Tags: java, spring, reactjs

I use React.js and Java Spring.

I connected google recaptcha to my site on localhost. It worked fine, but after a while, it stopped. On the website of Google Recaptcha, I got an this error.

> Your site does not check for reCAPTCHA solutions, which are necessary
>   for proper operation of reCAPTCHA.

On React side I connected captcha this way

> "npm install react-recaptcha-google --save"

and added this code

```
 <ReCaptcha
        ref={(el) => {this.captchaDemo = el;}}
        size="normal"
        data-theme="dark"            
        render="explicit"
        sitekey="my_site_key"
  />
```

**On Java Spring side i use the following code**

```
 private static final String CAPTCHA_URL = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=%s&response=%s";

@Value("${recaptcha.secret}")
    private String secret;

    @PostMapping("/register")
   public ResponseEntity<?> createNewCustomer(@Valid @RequestBody Customer customer, BindingResult result, HttpServletRequest request){
    validator.validate(customer,result);

    ResponseEntity<?> errorMap = exceptionMapHandler.exceptionResponse(result);
    if (errorMap != null) return errorMap;

    String url = String.format(CAPTCHA_URL,secret, request.getParameter("g-recaptcha-response"));
    CaptchaResponseDto captchaResponseDto = restTemplate.postForObject(url, Collections.emptyList(), CaptchaResponseDto.class);

    if (!captchaResponseDto.isSuccess()){
        throw new CaptchaException("Captcha not confirmed");
    }
    Customer saveCustomer = customerService.saveOrUpdate(customer,null);

    return new ResponseEntity<>(saveCustomer, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

**CaptchaResponseDto class**

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Getter
@Setter
public class CaptchaResponseDto {
    private boolean success;

    @JsonAlias("error-codes")
    private Set<String> errorCodes;
}
```

I decided to see what **request.getParameter("g-recaptcha-response")** takes.
And found out that this value is null.

As a result my url what I want to send google =

```
"https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=secret- 
 key&response=null"
```

As a result, I get the following error [**invalid-input-response**]

I checked the site key and the secret key and they are correct.

Again I repeat, this code worked perfectly.

How can this problem be solved?
Thanks for the help!